# Is Swap Space Needed for a Kafka Node ?

Tags: apache-kafka

We are in the midst of doing a Kafka POC between our enterprise and Google Cloud, and we were told that Google Cloud VMs dont provision swap space by default. Anyone in the Kafka community who implemented Kafka know whether Kafka needs swap space ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brokers themselves should not require a substantial amount of memory and as such do not require a swap space. Ideally you will run your brokers on dedicated VMs allowing the broker to take full advantage of the OS's buffer cache. In order to hit the expected latency levels the OS should have an abundant amount of 'free' memory. If you make it to the point where pages need to be swapped to disk you have already ventured into bad territory.

Answer (score 1):

You only need swap space if Kafka is running out of memory and in practice I haven't seen Kafka to be a huge memory hog.  So just be sure your VM is provisioned with enough memory and the swap space should not matter.